# How to get the entities defined within the java spring boot application to be reflected within a database without the use of CrudRepository

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I am building a web application using spring boot and mySQL. I have been following a video guide series to the letter but the author did not show how he set up the database.

This is the video I am stuck replicating the results from:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBfiEL-FomQ&index=7&list=PL2OrQJM8zmZ0k-S5FfR2qrwgupnaINO0m

I created a connection and schema using mySQL workbench.
I configured the app exactly how he did it but in his video, the entities created within the app show up as tables in his schema, whereas mine do not.

I tried importing his project code from his github , and ran it, but again it does not create the tables in my schema.

The application.properties configuration are as follow:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/freshvotes
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=example_user
spring.datasource.password=password123

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

This is the User Entity I created:

```
package com.freshvotes.domain;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String name;

@Id @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


}
```

The expected result is that as soon as I Run the app As Spring Boot App the Entities will show up as Tables within the Schema I created in mySQL localhost server.

What I get is nothing shows in my database server. Regardless of whether I have a schema created or not.
I even do not get an error in the IDE console when I ran the app with the server offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did get it to run as intended.
I had earlier run into an error while trying to build the project using maven, and added 3 dependencies to my pom.xml file. That got my project to build and run, but did not update the database.

I just commented those dependencies out again, but this time, it built properly, and runs as intended.

If you are curious about them these are the commented dependencies now:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you did download and install the MySQL Community version of MySQl on Windows from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/). 
I did not follow or watch this video guide, but I may point you to the official Spring documentation [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/).

once you have setup your db and added a user for your Spring application, you will need to get your connection string, like you did into your application.properties file. I did encounter some warnings and failures due to my crude setup without SSL so add `?useSSL=false` to your connection.

Also set your `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` to either create or create-drop (I use create-drop for testing only), otherwise Hibernate will not be able to create tables, just to update them.

Comment: In the guide you linked they used the _CrudRepository_ in an _interface_. I would like to do it without using that.
I will attempt to use _CrudRepository_ again, but I am hoping to get the code to run as it did in the video. It had less code and complications added to it.

If you want to check the result from the video, it's in the first minute of this one: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fphhJB7LIj0&index=8&list=PL2OrQJM8zmZ0k-S5FfR2qrwgupnaINO0m)
@hille